# How to know background processing of indexes done in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j 2.0.4, when I create an index using: CREATE INDEX ON :MOVIE(title), I got success result. As I know the processing is running in background. How can I know when this process is done? And How can I know whether index is applied in my queries or not? (like mongodb - explain()).

I am a newbie with Neo4j, hope to see your helps

Comment: you can also use `:schema await` to wait until the indexes are online

Comment: Is it possible to make `CREATE INDEX` wait until index is online? I wish they had a `WAIT` keyword to slap on at the end of the statement: `CREATE INDEX ON :MOVIE(title) WAIT` *(**do not use.** this is speculation, not valid syntax)*

Answer (score 3):

1. to check if a index has been populated completely: type `:schema` in Neo4j browser (not being sure if that is already available in 2.0.4, but it definitely is in 2.1.6)
2. in neo4j-shell (or the console as part of webadmin) you can prefix any Cypher statement using `profile <mystatement>`. This command will run the query and display the query plan indicating the usage of indexes as well. In the upcoming 2.2 release, Neo4j will have an `explain` command as well, that prints the query plan without executing it.

Comment: Would it be possible to update this answer for 2023?  What is the ideal way to wait for index creation in neo4j v4 or v5?